# why is one div not visible?

Tags: html, css

this is the div structure :

```
<div class=" wrap clear">
    <div class="block pink float"></div>
    <div class="block blue float"></div>
    <div class="block orange float"></div>
    <div class="block green see"></div>
</div>
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/GBdDU/6/)

What I did was adding a class named `see` which gave z-index 1000 to the green box. But I am still not able to see the box. I want to see the box without giving it a float left as to where it is. ?

Comment: also the `z-index` attribute wont work as the element position is not defined

Answer (score 6):

Add this to `.block`:

```
position:relative;
```

`z-index` only works for non-`static` elements.

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/6nT8E/)

Answer (score 0):

It's there, only that the DIV went back to the left side and displayed BEHIND the div's. You need to add "float" to it so it will automatically put DIV on left on the previous element.